# android app freezes on activity switch

Tags: java, android

I've got myself a mediocre game going for myself. It has a main menu activity that when you click play starts a new game play activity. When you lose the game you can either retry or go back to the main menu. the back button on the gameplay activity is just a ractangle with this coding.

```
if (GlobalVariables.GAMEOVER && backButton.contains((int)(event.getX()), (int)(event.getY())))
            {
                Intent backButtonIntent = new Intent(context, MainMenuActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(backButtonIntent);
            }
```

The program does not crash and it does switch to the mainmenu activity but it is frozen and no buttons are clickable. and here is the error i get.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.Canvas.drawColor(int, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode)' on a null object reference
 at android.view.SurfaceView.dispatchDraw(SurfaceView.java:451)
 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17472)
 at android.view.SurfaceView.draw(SurfaceView.java:442)
 at com.example.jordanschanzenbach.myapplication.GamePanel.draw(GamePanel.java:84)
 at com.example.jordanschanzenbach.myapplication.MainThread.run(MainThread.java:52)
```

here is the code that it is pointing to in the game panel. "super.draw(canvas)"

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.draw(canvas);
    backGround.draw(canvas);
    gameFloor.draw(canvas);
    gamePlayScene.draw(canvas);
}
```

i understand that this is a nullpointerexception and a duplicate question. but i dont understand why when i switch to my main menu activity it is causing this error when the game panel isn't even linked to the main menu activity. Please help a young student :) thank you and if you would like to see any other code i will edit this post immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the thread responsible for calling the `draw` method was left running before starting another activity. I'm not quite sure but it probably still tries to render on the SurfaceView even if it has already been detached from the window.

**Edit:**

I was able to replicate your problem. The thread that handles the drawing does not always instantly get the updated value of the variable you use as a while loop condition. You can choose to perform synchronization and/or other threading stuff, but you can simply try to break the while loop like how I did in the code below. Also, try to stop your drawing thread by making your while loop condition false inside the `SurfaceHolder.Callback#surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder)`.

```
public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private TextPaint paint;
    private volatile boolean isDrawing;
    private DrawingThread drawingThread;

    public GamePanel(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initialize();
    }

    // omitted the other constructors for brevity

    private void initialize() {
        ...
        drawingThread = new DrawingThread();

        // do this so that you can get an surface updates
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);

        canvas.drawText("Hello, world", 20, 20, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        isDrawing = true;
        drawingThread.start(); 
        // start drawing only after the surface was created
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) { }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        isDrawing = false; 
        // try to stop the drawing thread when the surface
        // is destroyed
    }

    private class DrawingThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (isDrawing) {
                try {
                    Canvas canvas = getHolder().lockCanvas();
                    // check if canvas is null just to make sure
                    if (canvas == null) break;
                    draw(canvas);
                    getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // This is thrown by SurfaceHolder#lockCanvas().
                    // Break when the surface has already been destroyed 
                    // but the variable `isDrawing` is still true.
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've never used the onDraw method. would i just simply change everything from Draw to onDraw? or would there be more to it? also, how would i go about initializing the super.Draw(canvas) so it is not null?

Comment: i just realized that my game activity onCreate method has this line of code in it which initializes my main thread and the draw method. was this what you mentioned i should not do? setContentView(new GamePanel(this));

Comment: im sorry, i greatly misunderstood your question. i focused on the SurfaceView stuff. maybe you failed to stop the MainThread instance in the activity from running before going back to the main menu. that thread probably still keeps on trying to draw on the surfaceview that's already detached from the window.

Comment: I think your right. I just tried to set my thread to false when i press that back button. unfortunately it crashed the game. BUT! it still went to the main menu and it worked? So setting the threads while loop to false crashed the application but the app still went to the main menu and worked...

Comment: can i not just set the while loop in my thread to stop running? are there certain steps i have to take?

Comment: I've successfully stopped my thread in a try catch but im still getting the nullpointerexception pointing at the same code above. the super.draw(canvas)

Comment: please see the edit i made on my answer and check if it solves your problem :)

Comment: i dont know if your still following this thread. but my issue is now pointing to my ontouch panel. i dont know why its crashing the program when i dont touch the screen besides the back button on the game play screen.

Comment: try posting a new question about the problem you're experiencing.